# List filtering and transformation

Tags: python, list, filtering, transformation

I have a list of library filenames that I need to filter against regular expression and then extract version number from those that match. This is the obvious way to do that:

```
libs = ['libIce.so.33', 'libIce.so.3.3.1', 'libIce.so.32', 'libIce.so.3.2.0']
versions = []
regex = re.compile('libIce.so\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
for l in libs:
    m = regex.match(l)
    if m:
        versions.append(m.group(1))
```

That produces the following list:

```
['3.3.1', '3.2.0']
```

Yet I feel that loop is not very 'Python style' and feel it should be possible to replace 'for' loop above with some smart one-liner.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about a list comprehension?

```
In [5]: versions = [m.group(1) for m in [regex.match(lib) for lib in libs] if m] 
In [6]: versions
Out[6]: ['3.3.1', '3.2.0']
```

Answer (score 8):

One more one-liner just to show other ways (I've also cleaned regexp a bit):

```
regex = re.compile(r'^libIce\.so\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$')
sum(map(regex.findall, libs), [])
```

But note, that your original version is more readable than all suggestions. Is it worth to change?

Comment: Thanks for both 'findall' and 'sum'!
Regarding readability - already used to it with all stl and boost algorithms :)

Comment: for some reason this one makes a lot more sense to me than the accepted/upvoted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
versions = [m.group(1) for m in [regex.match(l) for l in libs] if m]
```

I don't think it's very readable, though...

Maybe it's clearer done in two steps:

```
matches = [regex.match(l) for l in line]
versions = [m.group(1) for m in matches if m]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that isn't pythonic about using a standard for loop.  However, you can use the [map()](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=6251) function to generate a new list based on the results from a function run against each item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need to bother with regex for your simple case

```
>>> libs = ['libIce.so.33', 'libIce.so.3.3.1', 'libIce.so.32', 'libIce.so.3.2.0']
>>> libs
['libIce.so.33', 'libIce.so.3.3.1', 'libIce.so.32', 'libIce.so.3.2.0']
>>> for i in libs:
...   print i.split("so.")
...
['libIce.', '33']
['libIce.', '3.3.1']
['libIce.', '32']
['libIce.', '3.2.0']
>>> for i in libs:
...   print i.split("so.")[-1]
...
33
3.3.1
32
3.2.0
>>>
```

Do further checking to get those with "dots".

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
import re

def matches(regexp, list):
    'Regexp, [str] -> Iterable(Match or None)'
    return (regexp.match(s) for s in list)

libs = ['libIce.so.33', 'libIce.so.3.3.1', 'libIce.so.32', 'libIce.so.3.2.0']
regexp = re.compile('libIce.so\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
versions = [m.group(1) for m in matches(regexp, libs) if m is not None]

>>> print versions
['3.3.1', '3.2.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of was to combine 'map' and list comprehension.
The solution looks as below:

```
import re  
libs = ['libIce.so.33', 'libIce.so.3.3.1', 'libIce.so.32', 'libIce.so.3.2.0']  
versions = []  

regex = re.compile('libIce.so\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')  

def match(s):  
    m = regex.match(s)  
    if m:  
        return m.group(1)  

versions = [x for x in map(match,libs) if x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), it's possible to use a local variable within a list comprehension in order to avoid calling twice the result of the regex matching:

```
# libs = ['libIce.so.33', 'libIce.so.3.3.1', 'libIce.so.32', 'libIce.so.3.2.0']
# pattern = re.compile(r'libIce.so\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
[match.group(1) for lib in libs if (match := pattern.match(lib))]
# ['3.3.1', '3.2.0']
```

This:

- Names the evaluation of `pattern.match(lib)` as a variable `match` (which is either `None` or a `re.Match` object)
- Uses this `match` named expression in place (either `None` or a `Match`) to filter out non matching elements
- And re-uses `match` in the mapped value by extracting the first group (`match.group(1)`).